# Self-POST AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax

I am having some issues running an AJAX request to the php class that contains the AJAX request. The AJAX request is called used a button, and works partially.

My AJAX request is held in a header.php file, which is **included** in my kpi2.php. If I specify the "url" for the AJAX call to a test file (in the same directory) the POST is successful and I can see the output. I was under the impression if I removed the "url" option it would indeed post to the same page, what am I doing wrong here?

```
function executeRefresh(){
        if (control){
            $(".loader").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { refresh: '1' }, 
                success: function(json) {
                    if(!json.error) location.reload(true);
                    $(".loader").hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Output when no url is specified (meaning it should be posted to the same file that is calling the AJAX)

```
Written from /home/kpi/pages/kpi2.phpArray
(
)
```

This is the output when I have the option **url: "test.php"** (which has the exact same output but just in a different file.

```
Written from /home/kpi/pages/test.phpArray
(
    [0] => refresh
)
```

EDIT:
To obtain the output generated from above, a simple export.

```
$v1 = print_r(array_keys($_POST),true);
$fp = fopen('../data/output.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'Written from /home/kpi/pages/test.php'.$v1);
fclose($fp);
```

As for the control variable, it is just a simple listener that is true/false depending if the control key is clicked. It does indeed work and I've never had issues with it before.

As for the location.reload() I tried removing it and now it seems that it isn't even writing the php code now.

Comment: What are you outputting to get those two results. You didn't include that code in your question. Also, where does `control` come from in your javascript function? We are to assume its a higher up scope variable set to true? And then you have a `location.reload` without errors... is that conflicting with your test results?

Answer (score 0):

Originally in the header.php I had a button on the navbar that would call the AJAX function thus having the kpi2.php (which included the header.php) to have something posted to it. Once it was posted it would then call another php class.

Instead what I did was get rid of the onclick=executeRefresh() and then just listened to the button press specifically in the kpi2.php class. This way I could instantly execute the AJAX request to the other class without the un-needed post request to the class.

```
 $(function() {
        $(".btnRefresh").click( function()
            {
                if (control){
                    $(".loader").show();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"../setup/kpi_quality.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { casp: 'AVANT-CAP-321' }, // name of the post variable ($_POST['id'])
                        success: function(json) {
                            //if(!json.error) location.reload(true);
                            $(".loader").hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    });
```